# VBA for Excel: How to pull data from an Array in a private sub and use it in another private sub?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm very new to coding in VBA and with Excell. I'm creating a document control program and what I'm trying to do is everytime "Add Update"  button is pressed in the sheet store the already existing data in an array and put the new data in its place on sheet.

Then after "Show logs" button is pressed the contents of the array mentioned above is shown to the user.

Basicly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Lets say this is the array holding the data in it
example_array = Array("String1", "String2")
'I want to use the contents of the example_array in CommandButton2



UserForm1.Show


End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


MsgBox (example_array(0))
'So here I want to MsgBox to show to user "String1"



End Sub
```

Also I have to say, I do not know why I use Private Subs. I created the buttons Using Insert-ActiveX-Button and it automaticly added Private Subs so thats what I went with.

I tried making the example_array global by using

`Public example_array(1) As String`
`example_array = Array("String1","String2")`

But that did not worked.

I would appreciate any help and tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `CommandButton1_Click()` and `CommandButton2_Click()` should be in the worksheet module. `Private` isn't an issue.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    example_array = Array("String1", "String2")
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MsgBox example_array(0)
End Sub
```

- Define the public variable in a standard module ( VBE menu Insert>Module ) as below

```vb
Public example_array As Variant
```

Comment: Thank you. I was being a little dumb. :D

Answer (score 0):

### Global Variables

- Declare the variable outside of the scope of the procedures. Now both procedures see (have access to) it.

**Sheet Module**

- Right-click the tab of the sheet and select `View Code` or when in *Design Mode*, double-click any command button (ActiveX control).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private example_array As Variant

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    example_array = VBA.Array("String1", "String2")
    'UserForm1.Show ' irrelevant!
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If IsEmpty(example_array) Then
        MsgBox "The array is not populated!", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "The first element of the array is """ _
            & example_array(0) & """.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

- If any procedure outside of the sheet module needs access to the variable, declare it with the `Public` keyword:

  ```
   Public excample_array As Variant
  ```

  best in a *Standard* module so you can call it there with a simple `example_array` instead of using the sheet object e.g. `Sheet1.example_array`.

Comment: Thank you. 

If I may ask another question; If I want to store info on these arrays for a prolonged time do I need to hold them in a seperate sheet or each time we close and open the file it resets the data in arrays ?